# Why is my ArrayList of object showing empty when i have added objects to it?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot

I am working on a project which uses spring.
i have a service which returns a list of object 'Baby' to the Model Attribute.
For some reason after iterating through the loop and adding objects to the list ,i get list.IsEmpty() to be true. What am i doing wrong here ?
MY CONTROLLER CODE:

```
  @GetMapping("/print")
              public String print(Model model) throws SQLException {
                  System.out.println(email);
                  ResultSet rs=DB.resultset(email);
                  model.addAttribute("items", DB.createList(rs));
                  return "contribution";
              }
```

MY DBSERVICE CODE:

```
 public List<Baby> createList(ResultSet resultSet) throws SQLException {
    int count=0,i=0;
    ResultSet rs=resultSet;
    while(rs.next()){
        count++;
    }
    System.out.println(count);
    Baby baby[]=new Baby[count];
    List<Baby> list = new ArrayList<Baby>(count);
    while (resultSet.next()) {
        i=0;
        baby[i].setId(resultSet.getString("nameId"));
        baby[i].setName(resultSet.getString("name"));
        baby[i].setReligion(resultSet.getString("religion"));
        baby[i].setLocation(resultSet.getString("location"));
        list.add(baby[i]);
        i++;
        System.out.println(i);
        }
    System.out.println(list.isEmpty());
    return list;
}
```

BABY CLASS CODE:

```
package com.example.demo;
public class Baby {
private String id;
private String name;
private  String religion;
private String location;

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getLocation() {
    return location;
}

public String getReligion() {
    return religion;
}

public void setLocation(String location) {
    this.location = location;
}

public void setReligion(String religion) {
    this.religion = religion;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
```

}

Comment: Show source code of `resultset()` .

Comment: How does your code even run without a `NullPointerException`? When have you actually added new babies to your data structures (`baby` and `list`)?

Comment: What's the `count` value when you creating your arrayList?

Comment: @deHaar there is table in database which has all the baby names...thats not the problem here

Answer (score 4):

Your Problem is that you have try to loop over your ResultSet 2 times:

```
 while(rs.next()) {
     count++;
 }
```

Note that doing `ResultSet rs=resultSet;` will not create a copy of your ResultSet. Instead you now just have 2 variables pointing at one and the same ResultSet.

Once this loop is done your resultSet will have no more elements and next() on it will return false. So your second loop

```
while (resultSet.next()) {
    ....
}
```

where you try to add into your List is never entered at all.

Comment: but i created a temporary Resultset rs which i use to get my row count of table, if Resultset is a reference ,what do you suggest i should do?

Answer (score 1):

You have to create `Baby` instance as object. Then you have to put it in the array.Array has initialed size but you have to add instance from the class because else it does not have references. Actually you do not need array. Just put the `Baby` instance inside the list. Change your while loop like this inside DBSERVICE:

```
while (resultSet.next()) {
    Baby oneBaby = new Baby();
    oneBaby.setId(resultSet.getString("nameId"));
    oneBaby.setName(resultSet.getString("name"));
    oneBaby.setReligion(resultSet.getString("religion"));
    oneBaby.setLocation(resultSet.getString("location"));
    list.add(oneBaby);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public List<Baby> createList(ResultSet resultSet) throws SQLException {

  List<Baby> list = new ArrayList<Baby>();

  while (resultSet.next()) {
    Baby baby= new Baby();
    baby.setId(resultSet.getString("nameId"));
    baby.setName(resultSet.getString("name"));
    baby.setReligion(resultSet.getString("religion"));
    baby.setLocation(resultSet.getString("location"));
    list.add(baby);
  }

  return list;
}
```